# Can you specify the timezone when using read_parquet in R?

Tags: r, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file into R that has a timestamp column with values in EST. When I use `read_parquet` from the arrow package, it assumes that the values are in UTC. Is there a way to specify the time zone when reading the file?

```
library(arrow)
library(lubridate)

write_dataset(data.frame(timestep = seq(ymd_h("2023010112"), ymd_h("2023010212"), by = "hours"),
              "~/timeseriesexample",
              format="parquet")

d <- read_parquet("timeseriesexample/part-0.parquet")

tz(d[1,1])
# "UTC
```

I can use `force_tz` to fix the timezone after reading in the file, but I'd rather read it in correctly to begin with.

```
tz(force_tz(d[1,1], "America/New_York"))
# "America/New_York"
```

If I were creating the parquet files myself, I'd be able to specify the timezone when writing the data. In this case, though, I'm using data that's posted on AWS. For example,

```
s3://oedi-data-lake/nrel-pds-building-stock/end-use-load-profiles-for-us-building-stock/2022/resstock_amy2018_release_1/timeseries_individual_buildings/by_state/upgrade=0/state=AL/100066-0.parquet
```

Comment: Where is the code?????

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.